# Structure of a website in tree format?

Tags: html

How to generate a tree from HTML syntax on Windows? I tried xmllint on Linux but the output is in the indent format. What I want is like a tree structure.. correct me if I am wrong.

I want to take HTML as input, throw away all the texts and only left behind the tags in a structure view. So I can see a rough structure of a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just view it with Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: Is there any tool like xmllint? Because I want to call the program from my C++ program.